# POST Request Using Alamofire Not Working with Certain Characters When Set by TextField

Tags: swift, encryption, httprequest, alamofire

I have developed an iOS 15+ app in XCode 14 using Alamofire to send data to a node.js server that I developed and is running on my network. It sends a "note", which looks like the following:

```
struct Note: Decodable, Hashable {
    var _id: String
    var title: String
    var note: String
    var date: String
}
```

The app works great, except for when trying to send over a note that contains a few certain characters: single quote ('), double quote ("), new line, or emojis. So if I try to update a note with `note.note = "This isn't a note"`, it ends up saving the note as *This isn*. It ends the string just before the problem character.

The function that sends the .post request to update a note is contained within a class called APIFunctions and is shown here:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

    func updateNote(date: String, title: String, note: String, id: String) {
        print("From updateNote: " + note)
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "title" : title,
            "date" : date,
            "note" : note,
            "id" : id
        ]
        print(headers)
        AF.request("http://\(networkIP):8081/update", method: .post, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: (headers))
            .resume()
    }
```

There is a similar function for creating a new note with a */create* endpoint for the API. It has the same issue.

I have narrowed down where the problem takes place. Here is where the update function is being called:

```
import SwiftUI

struct NoteView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismissNoteView
    var note: Note  // Used to initialize var "sessionNote"
    @State var sessionNote: Note = Note(_id: "", title: "", note: "", date: "")
    let testNoteText = "This'll be interesting" //DEBUGGING
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.leading) {
            TextField("Note Title", text: $sessionNote.title)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)

                Text("Note text:")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    .padding(.leading, 5)

                TextEditor(text: $sessionNote.note)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)

            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear() {
            sessionNote = note
        }
        .navigationTitle(sessionNote.title)
        .toolbar {
            HStack {
                Button {
                    //Delete button that works just fine
                }
                Button {
                    sessionNote.date = currentDate()
                    let sendNote = sessionNote.note
                    print(sendNote)
                    APIFunctions.functions.updateNote(date: sessionNote.date, title: sessionNote.title, note: sendNote, id: sessionNote._id)
                    APIFunctions.functions.fetchNotes() {
                        dismissNoteView()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Save")
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `note` is passed into the `NoteView` from the `ContentView`. It contains the existing data for this note.

So when I run the app and I type *What's wrong* in the note `TextEditor` (or in the title `TextField`) it saves the note as `what`.

However, if I print `sendNote` or `sessionNote.note`, they appear correctly as *What's wrong*. The print statements in the function definition also print correctly as:

> From updateNote: What’s wrong
> title: Test Note
> date: November 21, 2022 at 8:12 PM
> note: What’s wrong
> id: 6371807a26e69d7f88594d3e

However (this is where it's weird), if I change the button action so that I pass a hardcoded value for the note by setting `let sendNote = testNoteText`, then it works as expected. If I click the save button in the app, the note saves as `This'll be interesting`. All of the print statements print as expected as well.

SO, the issue comes from the value being passed from the `TextEditor` OR `TextField`, but not when it is a hardcoded value. I am very confused as to why this is happening, especially since they appear to print exactly the same up until the point of the request being sent. I am guessing it has something to do with data encoding, which as a new programmer is not my greatest strength.

Any help is appreciated and let me know if more info is needed :).

Comment: Aside from your actual question, it's a little strange to be passing this kind of data in HTTP headers. You'd usually do this as data in the body of the request. I doubt TextEditor or TextField are the source of the issue. Like you said probably something in the encoding of the headers. You may need to escape certain characters like `\"` instead of `"`.

Comment: @AndrewCarter as it turns out the character that I thought was "APOSTROPHE" (') on the iPhone keyboard is actually "RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK" (') and therefore is treated differently. This is what caused the discrepancy, because on my desktop I was typing the actual apostrophe character. When I used the actual apostrophe in app, it worked.
Now the trouble is figuring out why the request does not work with these special characters (like ').